# How to declare all the namespace in dataweave

Tags: xml, mule, dataweave

My output xml from dataweave has the xml name space appearing in each element. Is there a way if all the namespace can appear in the root element

TIA

Comment: do not define %namespace derivative. Instead define it as an attribute for root element.    root @(xmlns="http://something.com/something") :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I found for my problem.

### Example code from data weaver

```
info:{
  field @(id: "!23" , value: payload.Response.Detail.Header.ID  ): null
}
```

### Soution

```
info:{
  field @(id: "!23" , value: payload.Response.Detail.Header.ID  ): {}
}
```

So as obvious from my answer I just replace the null part with {} , then it stops producing

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"
```